# Problem with smoke adaptive domain in Blender 2.8

Tags: smoke-simulation

When I create a smoke effect and turn on 'adaptive domain' the smoke starts jittering. Is it a bug or is there some setting I need to set? Seems that it doesn't happen in Blender 2.79.

[image]

You should see the issue by simply following this:

- open new blender session
- create a mesh cube
- create a quick smoke
- select domain and turn on 'adaptive domain'
- play it back and it is jittering

I haven't added any other things such as material/texture etc.

Comment: Can you share an image/animation to better explain the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth the jittering colors of smoke simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120941/smooth-the-jittering-colors-of-smoke-simulation)

Comment: @Leander this question is probably to be closed because it's unclear what OP is asking, but it isn't a dupe of the other one (at least it isn't clear). The other one was 2.79 (here andio says 2.79 works fine), and also it was specifically related to shading, while here it may have to do with just the simulation. I agree with putting on hold, but not to mark as dupe

Comment: hi guys, sorry i've just added the video in my post . pls have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, now it's definitely not a duplicate. I hope the close votes will be taken back.

Comment: Well, it's a beta software after all.