# Baked smoke shakes during render - Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[See render here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxzFs.jpg)

Smoke simulation is shaking / moving in Eevee render.

Blender 2.90.1

Comment: Does baking the light help? See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/128164/31447

Comment: @brockmann assuming I did it right, it did not help..

Comment: Would take some time to rebuild the smoke so most likely easier for all here if you'd share a file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/#

Comment: @brockmann I figured it out, this was due to Adaptive Domain being enabled. I remember now reading about this issue long ago, I guess they never bothered to fix it. Typical Blender stuff...

Comment: Cool! Do you mind adding that as an answer for future visitors?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While images and links are helpful additions, questions should stand on their own. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image or link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

The "shaking" is due to Adaptive Domain, as the domain adjusts to the size of the simulation it stretches and "moves" the smoke simulation. This is a known old issue as can be seen [here as well](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124619/problem-with-smoke-adaptive-domain-in-blender-2-8).